# docker-compose mongo needs read permissions for all

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, file-permissions

The [mongo](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) image has this nice mount option to initialize a database. You can mount `./initdb.d/` and `*.js` will be executed.

However, my project files and directories are `600` and `700` respectively, owned by `redsandro:redsandro`. The *mongo* image cannot read them.

It doesn't matter if I add group read + execute (dir) (i.e. `640` and `750`). Only when I add read permissions for all on the file, and read + execute permissions for all on the directory (i.e. `644` and `755`, let's call that *"plan C"*), will the mongo image execute the script.

Is there a way I can keep my files private on my machine (e.g. no permissions for `all` AKA `umask 007`) and still have the mongo *image* read them?

**Update:** I'm looking for a way to do this with docker-compose options, variables, environment etc. Not with building a custom image. E.g. some images that have similar problems allow me to simply set `user: 1000` (uid for local user). This doesn't work with the mongo image.

Comment: Do you change these files often?

Comment: @AlexBlex when I work on them, I change them dozens of times on a day. Then they remain untouched for over a month.

Answer (score 1):

You can [copy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) files instead of mounting the directory. E.g. your Dockerfile can be something like that:

```
FROM mongo

COPY --chown=mongodb:mongodb /host/path/to/scripts/* /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

It means each time you change the scripts you will need to rebuild the image, not just re-create the container. It's a tiny layer on top of the base image so it shouldn't take much time to build the image.

Comment: Upvoted, but I am aware of this option. Let's call this plan B.

Comment: The only other option is to use File ACL but it requires a custom image anyway since it's not installed in base mongo image. If you change files like dozen times per hour it would be better than copy. In your case it doesn't worth the hassle, so it's probably plan C.